# Why can't i write to my PrintWriter in my Java Web Socket Application?

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, glassfish

I am trying to make a web application that listens to a websocket and when a message arrives it receives it and send it again on a "normal" socket java.net.Socket so another server application would listen and receive it.

Here is the code for my Web Application

```
@ServerEndpoint("/messageendpoint")
public class WebListener {
    private static Set<Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());
    public static Session thisPeer;
    public static Socket socket;
    public static PrintWriter writer;
    public static OutputStream output1;


    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen (Session peer) {
        peers.add(peer);
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 9003);
            output1 = socket.getOutputStream();
            writer = new PrintWriter(output1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sendMessage("hello",peer);
        System.out.println("an opening");

    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+message);
        try {
                writer.println("vvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose (Session peer) {
        peers.remove(peer);

    }
}
```

and This is the code of the the other server which listens to the socket on port 9003

```
public class Buffer {
    public static void main(String []args){

        DataInputStream dis;
        PrintStream ps;
        BufferedReader in;
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9003);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            //dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while(true) {
                String str = dis.readLine();
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**What i expect from the code is that the server application should receive the message and print it on the screen.
What happens is the second application receives nothing (not even null)**

The same code runs perfectly and the message is received if i replaced the Web Socket Application with this simple code.

```
public class TestSender {
    public static void main(String []args){
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 9003);
            OutputStream output1 = socket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer =  new PrintWriter(output1);
            while (true) {
                writer.println("hello");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

which led me to think that the problem is in my understanding of javax.websocket library.

Comment: *What* is the problem? Do you get an error message? What happens and what is supposed to happen? Also try `flush()` on the `PrintWriter` after writing the message, as *autoflush* is disabled by default.

Comment: sorry, i will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, `PrintWriter` is buffered by default and the default buffer size is typically fairly large (8192 bytes). In addition to that, automatic flushing (on newline) of the `PrintWriter` is [off by default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream%29).

Since you never `flush()` the writer and thus force output to be written, the `PrintWriter` probably has your data still hidden in its buffer. This is also evidenced by the fact that continuous output seems to work.

Hence:

```
writer.println("vvvvvvvvvvvvvv");
writer.flush();
// ^^^^^^^ add this
```

Comment: indeed you are right but what i don't understand why it worked without flush when i tried it in the TestSender class.

Anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: Your `TestSender` class has a loop that continuously writes data. This will fill the `PrintWriter`'s buffer after a while and cause data to be written. In the *real* code you probably never tested with enough data to fill the buffer.